# Remove property from Json array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I get the content from a api response like this:

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:1337/" + route));
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

responseContent looks like this:

```
[{"caption":"Type Value List","name":"ReportsTypeValueList","visible":true,"enabled":true,"controlName":null,"elements":[{"caption":"Detail","name":"Detail","visible":true,"enabled":true,....
```

I parsed it into a Json array.

One of the json objects inside the json array has a property called `defaultValue`
with timestamp as it's value looking like this for example:

```
"defaultValue": "2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z"
```

How can I remove this property from the Json array?

Comment: Understanding why you need it removed might help.

Comment: what lib are you using for parsing the json objects?? Json.Net??

Comment: You parsed it to a `JArray` if you're using Json.NET. There's no such thing as a "Json array".

Comment: i thought JArray means Json Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Json.Net lib then you can do

```
JObject myJsonResponse = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
myJsonResponse.Property("defaultValue").Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
array.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value<string> 
("defaultValue") == "2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z").
Property("defaultValue").Remove();
```